# Find and remove <div> with correct "class" name I input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i have a sapmle html file:

```html
  
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <body>
        <div id="userlist2">
            <div class="Guest2">
                Guest2

                <p class="Guest2">2 to 1 new test json</p>
            </div>

            <div class="Guest4">
                Guest4

                <p class="Guest4">4 to 1</p>
            </div>

            <div class="Guest5">
                Guest5

                <p class="Guest5">5 to 1 betatest</p>
            </div>
          </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Now i want to search and remove `<div>` in `<div id="userlist2">` with correct class name I input, example: `"Guest2"`. So, how can i do it with Javascript or jquery ?

Sorry about snippet, i cant post this code with Code Sample, it always getting error `"It looks like your post is mostly code; please add some more details"`

Comment: One other option for the "mostly code" problem is to move your code into a jsfiddle and include a link & small sample in the post. :) jsfiddle.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this,

```
$("#userlist2").find(".Guest2").remove();
```

Note This will remove the element from the DOM,not hide it

Comment: How can i get message from this code if it success, @Varun ?

Comment: Message as in?? you can check if element was removed by following code `if ($(".Guest2").length > 0){
  //alert("div exist");
}else{ //deleted }`  @Thanhtu150

Comment: @Thanhtu150 No probs :)